# Mongoose CastError when trying to save variables to GeoJSON Point

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson, mongoose-schema

I am trying to add new users to a Mongo Database including their location as a GeoJSON object. I am using this package to predefine a Point object for the User Schema: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-geojson-schema

Specifically, the schema looks like this:

```
UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        first_name:String,
        last_name:String,
        username:String,
        avatar:String, //string to image location in server / public
        current_user_location: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point
    },
    { collection: 'users' });

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Then my route looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
router.post('/addUser', function (req, res) {
        var data = req.body;
        new User({
          first_name:data.first_name,
          last_name:data.last_name,
          username:data.user_name,
          avatar:data.avatar_link, //string to image location in server / public
          current_user_location: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [data.longitude, data.latitude] //[12.123456, 13.134578]
          }
        }).save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("done");
            }
     });
```

Then, when I use Postman to send a request Body it returns the error

> Cast to Point failed for value "{ type: 'Point', coordinates:
>   ['12.123456', '13.134578' ] }" at path "current_user_location"

Here is a picture of the request body:
[Postman addUser Request Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmwRA.png)

**But** when I change the 'coordinates' value in the route to static coordinates (the comment following it, [12.123456, 13.134578]) and test the route using Postman I get an OK and the new User is added to the database.

Is there something I'm missing with adding variable values to GeoJSON objects inside of request Bodies?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I wasn't strongly enough typing the passed coordinates. The Schema was receiving them as Strings and giving the error. Here is how to fix the offending line of code:

```
coordinates: [parseFloat(data.longitude), parseFloat(data.latitude)]
```

You must parse them to a float (especially with GeoJSON data because WGS84 specification says coords extend 5 decimal places)